# Populating spinner with browsers current URL

Tags: android, sqlite, url, android-webview

I'm very new to Android Developing (and stackoverflow).

I am trying to make an application that adds the URL of the website your currenty browsing into a spinner. The problem is simply that I don't know how to do this. I can't seem to find any way or solution to this, even tho I have been searching for a long time.

My code looks like this:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spesial:Tilfeldig");
    }

    [...]

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String label = inputLabel.getText().toString();

            if (label.trim().length() > 0) {
                // database handler
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                        getApplicationContext());

                // inserting new label into database
                db.insertLabel(label);

                // making input filed text to blank
                inputLabel.setText("");

                // Hiding the keyboard
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputLabel.getWindowToken(), 0);

                // loading spinner with newly added data
                loadSpinnerData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter label name",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

I would deeply appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your workflow? Are you trying to get the current URL from a `WebView` that's embedded in your app?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.
The onClick method is within the following class:
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);
  
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spesial:Tilfeldig");

I apologize for the bad formatting.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Please revise your question to include that code so that it has more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's `WebView` class has a `getUrl()` method that you can use. It returns a `String` that you can add to the adapter for your `Spinner`.

There's a `Spinner` tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) that goes over the details.